# About autocovariance of AR(2)

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

I'm trying to find the autocovariance function of AR(2) but get some trouble.
First, by **Yule-Walker**, I've got the equation:
$$γ(k) = ϕ_1γ(k-1)-ϕ_2γ(k-2)$$
But it still has no initial value for this equation. (For example, $ρ(0)=1$ for equation $ρ(k) = ϕ_1ρ(k-1)-ϕ_2ρ(k-2)$ can help us find an expression for ρ(k) which only contains $ϕ_1$ and $ϕ_2$).
Therefore, I try to find $γ(0)$ of AR(2)，which gives
$$γ(0) = \frac{2ϕ_1ϕ_2γ(1) + σ^2}{1-ϕ_1-ϕ_2}$$
(Computational detail can be check this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701126/finding-autocovariance-of-ar2?newreg=cfdb56c3c0b94549b12feed82041f533)).
However, this equation still contains $γ(1)$ so I can not calculate the value of $γ(k)$ for any $k$. This really confuses me. 
I really appreciate if someone can help me with this confusion.

Answer (score 3):

When the AR(2) process $(1 - \phi_1B - \phi_2B^2)X_t = Z_t$ is causal$^\dagger$, Example 3.3.5 in *Time Series: Theory and Methods* by P. J. Brockwell and R. A. Davis gives the general term formula of $\gamma(h)$ as follows:

> \begin{align}
> \gamma(h) = \frac{\sigma^2\xi_1^2\xi_2^2}{(\xi_1\xi_2 - 1)(\xi_2 - \xi_1)}[(\xi_1^2 - 1)^{-1}\xi_1^{1 - h} - (\xi_2^2 - 1)^{-1}\xi_2^{1 - h}], \tag{1}
> \end{align}
> where $\xi_1, \xi_2$ are the zeros of the quadratic equation $1 - \phi_1z - \phi_2z^2 = 0$.

---

$^\dagger$ Causality requires that in $(1)$, $|\xi_1| > 1, |\xi_2| > 1$. $(1)$ only treats the case that $\xi_1 \neq \xi_2$.  The case $\xi_1 = \xi_2$ is covered in Example 3.3.4, where the general term formula for $\gamma(h)$ of the causal AR($p$) process is given as:
\begin{align}
\gamma(h) = \sum_{i = 1}^k\sum_{j = 0}^{r_i - 1}\beta_{ij}h^j\xi_i^{-h}, \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $\xi_i, i = 1, \ldots, k$, are the zeros (possibly complex) of $\phi(z)$, and $r_i$ is the multiplicity of $\xi_i$, the constants $\beta_{ij}$ are determined by boundary conditions:
\begin{align}
& \gamma(0) - \phi_1\gamma(- 1) - \cdots - \phi_p\gamma(- p) = \sigma^2, \\
& \gamma(k) - \phi_1\gamma(k - 1) - \cdots - \phi_p\gamma(k - p) = 0, k \geq 1. \tag{3}
\end{align}

When $p = 2, k = 1, r_1 = 2$, we have $\phi_2 = -\frac{1}{4}\phi_1^2$, $(2)$ becomes
\begin{align}
\gamma(h) = \beta_{10} + \beta_{11}h\xi. \tag{4}
\end{align}

and $(3)$ becomes:
\begin{align}
& \gamma(0) - \phi_1\gamma(1) - \phi_2\gamma_2(2) = \sigma^2, \\
& \gamma(1) - \phi_1\gamma(0) - \phi_2\gamma_2(1) = 0, \\
& \gamma(2) - \phi_1\gamma(1) - \phi_2\gamma_2(0) = 0. \tag{5}
\end{align}

Solving $(5)$ yields
\begin{align}
& \gamma(0) = \frac{64 + 16\phi_1^2}{64 - 48\phi_1^2 + 12\phi_1^4 - \phi_1^6}\sigma^2, \\
& \gamma(1) = \frac{64\phi_1}{64 - 48\phi_1^2 + 12\phi_1^4 - \phi_1^6}\sigma^2, \\
& \gamma(2) = \frac{48\phi_1^2 - 4\phi_1^4}{64 - 48\phi_1^2 + 12\phi_1^4 - \phi_1^6}\sigma^2.
\end{align}
It then follows by $(4)$ and $\phi_1 = 2\xi^{-1}$ that
\begin{align}
& \beta_{10} = \gamma(0) = \frac{1 + \xi^{-2}}{（1 - \xi^{-2})^3}\sigma^2, \\
& \beta_{11} = (\gamma(1) - \beta_{10})\xi^{-1}
=-\frac{\xi^{-1}(1 - \xi^{-1})^2}{(1 - \xi^{-2})^3}\sigma^2.
\end{align}

This shows that the autocovariance function of the AR($2$) process $(1 - \xi^{-1}B)^2X_t = Z_t$ is
\begin{align}
\gamma(h) = \frac{1 + \xi^{-2}}{(1 - \xi^{-2})^3} - 
\frac{(1 - \xi^{-1})^2}{(1 - \xi^{-2})^3}h.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Hi: You can calculate it directly. I won't do the whole thing but I think that I can give you enough that you can do the rest.  First write out the process for $x_t$, $x_{t+1}$, $x_{t+2}$ and $x_{t+3}$.

$x_{t} = \phi_1 x_{t-1} + \phi_2 x_{t-2} + \epsilon_t$

$x_{t+1} = \phi_1 x_{t} + \phi_2 x_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t+1}$

$x_{t+2} = \phi_1 x_{t+1} + \phi_2 x_{t} + \epsilon_{t+2}$

$x_{t+3} = \phi_1 x_{t+2} + \phi_2 x_{t+1} + \epsilon_{t+3}$

First calculate the unconditional variance of $x_{t}$.

Next, calculate the correlation between $x_{t+1}$ and $x_{t}$ (which is the covariance of $x_{t+1}$ and $x_{t}$ divided by unconditional variance of $x_{t}$).

Next, calculate the correlation between $x_{t+2}$ and $x_{t}$.

Then, calculate correlation between $x_{t+3}$ and $x_{t}$.

You should start to see a pattern. I hope this helps.

Comment: I performed the calculations according to your insturction: 
Unconditional variance of $x_t$:$γ(0) = \frac{2ϕ_1ϕ_2γ(1) + σ^2}{1-ϕ_1-ϕ_2}$. 
Correlation between $x_{t}$ and $x_{t+1}$：$ρ(1) = ϕ_1ρ(2)+ϕ_2ρ(3)$. 
Correlation between $x_{t}$ and $x_{t+2}$：$ρ(2) = ϕ_1ρ(3)+ϕ_2ρ(4)$. 
Correlation between $x_{t}$ and $x_{t+3}$：$ρ(3) = ϕ_1ρ(4)+ϕ_2ρ(5)$. 
But it seems the value of $γ(0)$ is still not found, could you please give me more detials, many thanks!

Comment: Hi: My hint really isn't all that useful for this case. But,  if you google for "unconditional variance of AR(2)", the first thing that comes up should be a document that provides all of the gory details. If that doesn't happen, let me know. the document is at the link www2.econ.osaka-u.ac.jp but that's not the whole link. I can't figure out what the link is or I'd just send you that.  document is titled 08.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

1. The equation for gamma(0) (which must be corrected by squaring the phi coefficients at the denominator) involves gamma(1).
2. The recursive equation for gamma(1) involves gamma(0) (recall that gamma(-1)=gamma(1), by stationarity)
3. You then have a system of two equations; solve it getting the values of gamma(0) and gamma(1).
4. Use these values for computing all of the other autocovariances, recursively